# Whats the difference between using boost::this_thread::sleep_for() and regular sleep() function?

Tags: c++, boost, sleep, boost-thread

We know that `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(...)` can be used for putting the currently running thread into sleep. How different it is from the regular `sleep()` function. It seems everyplace where we use `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(...)` can be simply replaced by `sleep()` method without affecting the results. Can anyone throw some light into it.

Comment: `sleep()` isn't portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ didn't provide a sleep function until C++11 came along, which offers [std::thread::sleep_for()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).  So Boost provides its own for making your code platform-independent.

The C functions [sleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep), [usleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep), and [Sleep()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are platform-specific rather than part of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

sleep operates only at an one second level of granularity, as were boost::this_thread::sleep_for allows for sub 1 second granularity for the sleep.